# Open Street Map Routing using Ships

Tags: api, openstreetmap

I want to know if is there a way to use the Open Street Map API to know the distances of ships and getting the distance of two points.

Maybe there is a profile for it. I have searched for Marine Navigation and OSMR but I didn't find anything.

Comment: I know someone that customized GraphHopper to do this. But you have to model all possible routes how the ship can go and/or also add area routing support or a workaround for it: https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/issues/82

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have recently asked this question here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/242387/open-street-map-routing-using-ships-and-trains
And there is a great Answer and a solution.